# Php-mysql :Database designs for adding packages with more than one exclusions for one package

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have Following scenario

1.User  creates a new package with some data.

```
 table-name: packages
-----------------------
  id:(PK) int
  small_description: text
```

2.User adds some exclusions to previously added Packages.

```
table-name: exlusions
 --------------------------
  id:(PK) -int
  package_id:(FK) - refers packages table
  description: -text
```

Now i need third option such as a user can able to group some exclusions under a name (call it as  **template name**) and able to link it with previously  added packages (ie, step 2)

For that i am using the following table schema

```
table-name: exclusions_templates(For storing template names)
-----------------------

  id:(PK) -int
  template_name -varchar

  table-name: exclusions_templates_items (Exlusions under one template name)
--------------------------
  id:(PK) -int
  template_id:(FK) - refers exclusions_templates table
  description: -text
```

But how can i link `exclusions_templates` with `packages` table, currently it has only a one to many  relationship with `exlusions` table.
Do i need to change the above the schema getting my desired result??

**UPDATE**

I want to get all exclusion of a particular package ,may be packages table is linked with template-name table or exlusions table

Comment: You need to add another FK for new 1:m relation.

Comment: @AlexBlex could you please explain??

Comment: Sure thing. What's your *desired result*? I mean, how do you want the tables linked?

Comment: @AlexBlex but what about of more than one template_name for package table??

Comment: @AlexBlex Whether it is  linked with template_name or not i want to get all the exlusions for a particular package

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking. Please update the question with expected behaviour. From current edition it is not quite clear whether you want to *group some exclusions under a name* or group packages somehow.

Comment: @AlexBlex Updated my question

Comment: You can get all exclusions of a particular package by `package_id:(FK) - refers packages table`. The `may be` part of the question is quite confusing tho. `packages` is linked with `exclusions`, and is not linked with `exclusions_templates`, if it is what you refer to as *"template-name table"*.